# Understanding (non-degenerate and degenerate) Perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory

I was learning the basics of [perturbation theory (PT) in QM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)), and I had quite a bit of trouble with it, especially (time independent) degenerate PT. My reference books are primarily Sakurai (became too difficult after a while due to its emphasis on operators), Konishi and Pafutti (better but no applications), Landau (extremely brief), Shankar (very little of degenerate PT) and Griffiths (confused me a lot about "good" states, but once I got an idea of what it meant it started making sense). My purpose in creating this post is to verify whether what I have understood on my own terms is even partly correct and to clear a doubt I had.
After all this, I came to the following conclusions:

1. We initially start with a diagonalised observable ($H_{0}$, and a complete, orthonormal set of its eigenkets, our states, $|n \rangle$) and add a perturbation, $V$, that affects this and, in general, gives us a new operator, $H$, that is not diagonal.
2. In non-degenerate PT, the first order change in energy is simply the expectation of $V$ between our original states, while the first order change in the states contributes a change to every "component" of the state $|n\rangle$ except for the $n^{th}$ direction itself (which is implemented by the condition on the sum $k \neq n$ and is due to an orthonormalisation we subject the system to, $\langle n|\psi \rangle = 1$ where $|\psi\rangle = |n\rangle + |n^{(1)}\rangle + ...$, the new state).
3. In degenerate PT, the degeneracy can lead to $E_{k}^{(0)} = E_{n}^{(0)}$ even for $k \neq n$. This term occurs in the denominator of the first order states in non degenerate PT, so causes terms to blow up if we blindly extend the same ideas here. For this reason, we find "good" states, which are basically the eigenstates of the total $H$. These enable us to diagonalise $H$, which means that now the new energy values $E_{n} = E_{n}^{(0)} +  E_{n}^{(1)} + ...$ are basically the eigenvalues of $H$, while the new states are simply our "good" states (in the first order). The eigenvalues are derived through expectation between diagonal states (since off diagonal elements are 0 in a diagonalised matrix). This can lead to either a total or a partial lifting of degeneracy.
4. A second approach to degenerate PT involves writing out the secular equation for $H$ and solving for $\Delta E$, which is evidently the same as finding out the eigenvalues, except we have explicitly removed the original $E^{(0)}$ part from each energy $E$. This is the approach followed in my course and Landau (as far as I remember); the advantage is that you don't need to "think" about good states, you simply follow steps and get a result. The disadvantage is that most books don't follow this approach and students end up being completely confused. Both approaches are actually the same (eignevalues, eigenvectors) but may seem different to someone who is new, especially because most books say a lot about "good states" instead of just saying that they are the new eigenstates.

Assuming that these previous points reflecting my understanding of the subject are more or less correct, I have the following questions:

1. In non-degenerate PT, what is the validity of the orthonormalisation condition I mentioned? I understand the physical idea behind it somewhat - that the perturbation is so small, that in the first order none of the states are affected in their original directions but rather the effect is in the directions where they are 0 (i.e., its like saying that if we change a vector pointing in the z direction by a slight perturbation through another random vector, then the change in x, y directions is more, since originally those directions had 0 magnitude, but the change in z is small, since the original vector pointed in that direction and our perturbation is small).
2. Given a matrix, $M$, the standard way to proceed is to diagonalise it, get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors (the procedure outlined in point 3 above). Therefore, why do we not diagonalise $H$ in non degenerate PT and instead do what we do, take expectation between original states that do *not* diagonalise $H$ necessarily? This is like saying that we expect a change only in the diagonal elements (maybe because we are in the first order?), because $V$ is not necessarily diagonal and $H$ may have off diagonal terms. If we neglect those and simply determine $\langle n|V|n \rangle$, and compare with what we do in point 3 above, this is like saying that in the first order we are assuming that the off diagonal terms play *no* role and the original states are good enough to diagonalise this new matrix (which cannot be true since we have a separate expression for $|\psi^{(1)}\rangle$). I do understand the math behind the results, but intuitively, given a matrix, my first instinct will be to try and diagonalise it (something which we evidently do in degenerate PT by getting the good states). So, there must be either an advantage or a physical (or non physical) reason for the steps we follow, and I am not sure what that is.

Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S. I did search the forum here for similar questions, and while loads of question on Sakurai's approach or PT lie around, I do not think my questions have been repeated anywhere. Also, another point I have here is to verify whether my own conceptual understanding of what is going on is correct.

Comment: The benefit of perturbation theory (PT) is that you don't need to construct the full Hamiltonian  $H$, which you would need if you wanted to do a diagonalization. You can improve the results with PT for a specific state without  the need to calculate all possible off diagonal elements. Only in the degenerate case you are forced to do a diagonalization, but just inside a subspace spanned by the degenerate states which is much smaller than the full Hamiltonian and thus easier to calculate in general. I hope this addresses some points of question part (2).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, @HansWurst. Yes, it does make things a bit clearer to me!